# How do I delay a static created boot method until relationships have been formed?

Tags: laravel

Just a short backdrop to my current issue; currently I am trying to create multiple recurring events associated with a booking, from my original `Enquiry`. My enquiries generate a `Booking` relationship and then I have a has-many-through of `BookingEvents` that links everything together.

My `self::updated` method works as required & expected and I basically need the `self::created` method to work the same, but at the created point the relationships aren't laced together by the time the code fires.

For example:

```php
self::created(function ($enquiry) {         
    if($enquiry->recurring == true) {               
        if($enquiry->booking) { # Problem 1
            if($enquiry->booking->first_event) { # Problem 2
                $evt = $enquiry->booking->first_event;
                    ...
```

Of course I imagine there are solutions that require total refactoring (there always are) but is there a way I could just delay the actions of the created method momentarily until relationships are formed?

Comment: You can try using `self::creating`

Comment: @aceraven777 well the relationships definitely don't exist on `creating` if they don't exist on `created` but thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Given that I have a `BookingEvent` HasManyThrough relationship model, I added a `static::created` boot method to that model instead, I create an initial event and that triggers the recurring event creation. I just add a small check to see whether or not the `initial_event` boolean is true, to avoid an infinite loop.

```
class BookingEvent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'booking_event';
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::created(function($relationship) {

            $booking = Booking::find((int)$relationship->booking_id);
            $event = Event::find((int)$relationship->event_id);

            # Handle recurring
            $enquiry = $booking->enquiry;
            if($event->initial_event == true && $enquiry->recurring == true) {   
            if($enquiry->booking) {
                if($enquiry->booking->first_event) {
                    $evt = $enquiry->booking->first_event;
                        ...
```

For other folks interested in this topic, a third party solution that listens to extended relationship events may help:
https://github.com/chelout/laravel-relationship-events